# Same URL for different subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, subdomain

I have different views for desktop and mobile site. If site is opened from mobile device then it will be redirected to `m.domain_name`

> ```
> root :to => "home#index", constraints: {subdomain: 'm'||'m.staging'}
> root :to => 'desktop#index'
> ```

It works fine for 'm' subdomain however it isn't working for `m.staging` subdomain

Comment: do you mean something like `http://m.staging.yourwebsite.com` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [Request based constraint](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), the request property should return String, not true/false. Try the same using a lambda,

```
root :to => "home#index",
constraints: lambda { |request| ['m','m.staging'].include?(request.subdomain) }
```

Comment: but why did it work for 'm' subdomain and not for 'm.staging'?

Comment: did you try only with 'm.staging' like ` constraints: {subdomain: 'm.staging'} ?